# Using Bing Maps REST Services on BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, maps, bing-maps

Are there any third party libraries or SDK's - commercial or open source - that would provide a straightforward way to integrate Bing Maps in a BlackBerry application? Now that Bing Maps Mobile is free for use in consumer-facing apps, it's a really compelling choice.

[Nutiteq](http://www.nutiteq.com/) provides the only option I've found so far (short of developing in house). Hoping there are others.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you not using Google Maps or Open Street Maps? Is there a specific requirement there?

Comment: Google Maps licensing fees are prohibitively expensive. Open Street Maps is a viable option as far as the tiling goes, but in and of itself isn't enough -- a lot of coding goes into actual providing a map that works.

Answer (score 0):

Bing maps has a REST API. You can see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701722.aspx

However, I am not sure about any SDK for Blackberry. Check if any unofficial project has used this REST API to create a wrapper for Blackberry. Otherwise, you can always use the browser field to fetch the map tiles.